# Иерархия объектов

Tags: c#, наследование

Не могу построить иерархию классов. Инженер, персона, Ведущий инженер, рабочая команда.

Пока так сделал:
Персона — это базовый класс, инженер и Ведущий инженер от него наследуются, у них есть поле Команда. В классе Ведущий инженер есть List. А вот класс Команды не вписывается...

Comment: Скорее как-раз Команда дожна быть классом, который содержит список персон. Зачем Ведущему инженеру список?

Comment: @CrazyElf я думаю что это типо как ведущий инженер имеет команду обычных инженеров (которые собственно в списке)

Comment: Ну тогда пусть у него будет поле "Команда" собственно, у Ведущего, а в этой команде уже простые инженеры. А, собственно у вас же так и сказано. Вам просто нужно понять, что Команда - это и есть список Персон. Ну, если я всё правильно понял.

Comment: За вас никто работать не будет. Показывайте свои наработки, что сделали, что не получилось. Показывайте код!

Answer (score 0):

Рабочая команда (имеет поле Лист персон)

Персона (имеет поле Должность)

Ведущий инженер и Инженер (Классы, которые наследуются от Персоны. Имеют разные методы)